# Using <img> in Bootstrap Modal Box

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I have a couple of working modal boxes on my site and I am trying to add a new one. The existing boxes only have plain text and have not been an issue.

The new one has an IMG in the modal body but when I refresh the page the modal box is loaded and sits at the top of my site, if I remove the image it works as expected (minus the image)

Link code:

```
<a href="#clarissa" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Clarissa Bonnel</a>
```

Modal Box:

http://jsfiddle.net/wan4q/

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/wan4q/2/) which contains the working modal with image.

Code:

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>

<body>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://vmatechs.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/android.jpg" alt="image" />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
 </div><!-- /.modal -->  
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
```

this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/wan4q/3/) to working modal with image and text

Comment: Really confused. I have replacxed my bootstrap refferences with the same as yours and it makes no difference. is it possible to discuss privately as I cannot publish the link to the live page at the moment.

Comment: The modal just loads at the bottom of my web page now. when using the css and js provide in your demo in the same places

Comment: My code now kind of works. the box is not shown when the page loads but when you click the link for the modal box to open the black overlay loads but no box?

Comment: what do you exactly want on the modal?

Comment: I need 3 modal's

1) Has 3 buttons in that link to third party websites
1) with a picture in and a description
1) with picture and description

Comment: http://goo.gl/9kIoZP this is a link to the current site model. would you be able to help me fix it on that version? Thanks

Comment: whats problem with the code given in jsfiddle link..? modal code in your jsfiddle has some errors..

Comment: even when using the jsfiddle it does not work within my web page. i thought if you had a copy of my web page then you would be able to compare against what I have.

Comment: i have corrected your jsfiddle.. its working.. check it.. http://jsfiddle.net/wan4q/5/

Comment: your images is not shown since its not exist.. see this http://jsfiddle.net/wan4q/6/

Comment: http://goo.gl/cJ1vBG < modal with picture shows up but with an odd scrollbar to the side and the modal box for the take our survey button no longer works.

Comment: 1) change <a role="button"> to <a role="dialog">
2) remove the class 'hide' in your first modal div.

Comment: try writing your modals code exactly before end of body tag, i mean out of all divs(header, footer, container etc)

Comment: The modals are right at the bottom out of everything by </body> also I have removed the overflow and the scrollbar has gone but the first modal still isn't right and the 2nd with the image is not in the center of the page

Comment: is everything written using bootstrap in your website?

Comment: No it is used for the grid and i also want to use it for the modal. nothing else should use it but because of the bootstrap css it has changed all the text formatting too

Comment: change this in your modal class 
.modal{left:20%; right:20%; top:10%; bottom:10%; width:60%; overflow:auto;}

Thats it..

Comment: is there no css file just for the modal elements so there is no crossover between that and other styles I have?

Comment: oh boy.. i told you to just replace those values not to remove all style elements..

Comment: so final .modal class should look like this...
.modal {
left: 20%;
right: 20%;
top: 10%;
bottom: 10%;
width: 60%;
overflow: auto;
position: fixed;
z-index: 2000;
display: none;
}

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't realized I had overwritten them all. I have now correctly made those changes. The 1st modal loads correctly but with no background.

2nd modal with image loads but still has that scrollbar.

Comment: first modal has no body because you have missed two div tags.. 
1)<div class="modal-dialog"></div>.......
2)<div class="modal-content"></div>.....
check and correct it..

Comment: second box will obviously have scroll bar if the content of it exceeds.. otherwise it will be hidden..

Comment: Understand that but the scrollbar is outside of the box. is it not possible to have scrollbar within the box?

Answer (score 1):

This code is working perfectly well. May be you might not have included the jquery and bootstrap js files

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Amit Wecomes you</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />    
</head>
<body>
<a href="#clarissa" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Clarissa Bonnel</a>
<!-- Modal -->
 <div id="clarissa" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-   labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-header">
   <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;   </button></p>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
         <img src="images/amit.jpg" align="left"/>
         I am Clarissa. I am also 34 years old,    half Italian - half French with a little Australian and Romanian twist. I speak 5 languages. My career has been a roller coaster in terms of locations and roles. For more than 11 years, I have lived and worked across the globe, mainly in international organisations, media and professional services, in journalism, sales, client relationship management and event organising. Throughout this journey, I have met a lot of people who have become frustrated because of a mismatch between their goal in life and their current situation without any plan for them to get what they want and deserve.
     </div>
   </div>

   <!-- End Modal -->
<script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Use this code, I have placed your content inside my modal and its working fine. I used another image to try out your code.

Enjoy Cheers!!!

Comment: As I said before, I have modal boxes already working and it works if I remove the image. are you able to provide me with your bootstrap fiels so I can compare? I have this:      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modal.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: If the image exists then the modal box loads as I explained previously but if the image link is broken the modal works but the img does not.

Comment: Ok modal.js is already present inside the bootstrap.js file, I don't understand why are you including it again.

Comment: I have removed modal.js and it makes no difference.

Comment: Put the jquery file before bootstrap.js

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to include this because I searched for days for this answer as to why an image broke the css in the bootstrap modal. I am adding this to the bottom because the answer is hidden within all the comments at the top of the page and others may be looking for it.

The actual answer that worked for me was the change in the CSS that Girish Gowda provided. I wanted to give credit where credit is due.

so final `.modal` class should look like this...

```
.modal {
    left: 20%; 
    right: 20%; 
    top: 10%; 
    bottom: 10%; 
    width: 60%; 
    overflow: auto; 
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: 2000; 
    display: none; 
}
```

I will say that I did end up changing the `left: 20%` to `40%` as my modal was showing up off the left side of the screen, but other than that this fixed all the CSS confusion problems that the image caused. Thank you to Girish Gowda for the answer.